# Confirming a statement in the simple past with the present perfect

Tags: questions, present-perfect, past-simple

Is this really necessary or natural to use the present perfect to confirm a statement with the simple past ?

> A: I **saw** the Eiffel Tower.
>    B: Oh, you **have seen** the Eiffel Tower ?

Comment: The first is a statement (not a question) and the second is a question (not an answer).  The choice of tense will depend on the context and meaning desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is natural to ask (in a variety of contexts)

**Have you seen the Eiffel Tower?**

A person visiting Paris and "seeing the sights" might be asked that question by a friend from home who had been living in Paris for a while as an ex-pat or as a student on a year-abroad program.

It's also natural to *confirm*:

**So, you *have* seen the Eiffel tower. I was under the impression you had decided to skip France on your trip to Europe.**

A person back home might say such a thing to the traveler to Europe upon his return.

Comment: But is normal to use this conversation as an example of present perfect in general in order to teach English to non English speakers ?

Comment: I would not know.